# A Plot like PyLDAVis for Visualizing Common Words between Columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud, venn-diagram, pyldavis

I have a dataset where I have multiple text-type columns (150+), and I want to be able to visualize the common words between all of them, as well as their own separate words. I tried using venn-diagram plots by matplotlib but they're restricted to 3 sets only.

I'm interested to know - is there a way I can plot the pyLDAVis plot for all my columns as sets on the left of the venn-diagram, and my vocabulary (756 words) on the right?

Or perhaps there's another way of plotting multiple word-clouds and showing their intersection?

Much appreciated.

Comment: This type of question is off-topic. Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more, because this type of question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [import pyLDAvis.gensim](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/projects/2019-07-19_fraud_detection_python/2019-07-19_fraud_detection_python.html#To-understand-topics,-you-need-to-visualize)